# MarkerCluster element popup does not appear when clicking a spiderfy element, instead unspiderfy is triggered in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, clustering, markers, leaflet-plugins

I have created a custom popup that appears whenever an element on my map is clicked. However, when spiderfy happens (when a marker cluster is clicked and the map cannot zoom to a level that would separate the elements), clicking a spiderfy element does not cause the popup to appear. Instead, it just triggers unspiderfy.

Is there a way to make this work the way I want, so that clicking a spiderfy element does not cause unspiderfy and instead causes the element popup to appear? (I use these popups to show element-specific information to the user.)

Relevant code:

```
function popUp(f, l) {
    var out = [];
    if (f.properties) {
        for (key in f.properties) {
            out.push(key + ": " + f.properties[key]);
        }
        l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    }
}

function getStyle(feature, items) {
    return {
        weight: 3,
        opacity: 1,
        color: [...another function call...],
        fillOpacity: 0.7
    }
}

function createLayer(url, treatments, layerID) {
    var sectionLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX([url], {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        },
        onEachFeature: popUp,
        style: function (feature) {
            return getStyle(feature, treatments);
        },
        pointToLayer: function (geojson, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
                fill: true,
                opacity: 0.7,
                color: [...another function call...],
                weight: 5,
                radius: 6,
                fillColor: [...another function call...],
                fillOpacity: 0.6
            });
        },
        pane: layerID,
        middleware: function (data) {
            var features = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++) {
                if (data.value[i].Mapping && data.value[i].Mapping.coordinates[0] !== 0 && data.value[i].Mapping.coordinates[1] !== 0) {
                    var element = data.value[i];

                    var mapping = reprojectMapping(data.value[i].Mapping);

                    var geojsonFeature = {
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "properties": {
                            "Name": element.Name,
                            "Details": element["Treatment"],
                            "Street View": getStreetView(mapping)
                        },
                        "geometry": mapping
                    };

                    geojsonFeature.properties["Treatment"] = element["Treatment"];

                    features.push(geojsonFeature);
                }
            }

            return features;
        }
    });

    sectionLayer.on('data:loaded', function () {
        addMapLayerToMap(sectionLayer, layerID);
    });
}

function addMapLayerToMap(geoJsonLayer, layerID) {
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport({
        clusterPane: layerID.toString()
    });

    // Add layer to cluster
    markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
    map.addLayer(markers);
}
```

(For what it's worth, this code works fine for showing the popup on non-spiderfy elements.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add popups to GeoJSON layer markers and then add GeoJSON layer to cluster layer, popups get lost for spiderified markers.

Solution is to add popups to GeoJSON layer markers and then add those markers directly to cluster layer, all this within `onEachFeature` option function.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function createLayer(url, treatments, layerID) {
  var markers = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport({
      clusterPane: layerID.toString()
  });
  var sectionLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX([url], {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      popUp(feature, layer);
      markers.addLayer(layer);
    },
    style: function (feature) {
      return getStyle(feature, treatments);
    },
    pointToLayer: function (geojson, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
        fill: true,
        opacity: 0.7,
        color: [...another function call...],
        weight: 5,
        radius: 6,
        fillColor: [...another function call...],
        fillOpacity: 0.6
      });
    },
    pane: layerID,
    middleware: function (data) {
      var features = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++) {
        if (data.value[i].Mapping && data.value[i].Mapping.coordinates[0] !== 0 && data.value[i].Mapping.coordinates[1] !== 0) {
          var element = data.value[i];
          var mapping = reprojectMapping(data.value[i].Mapping);
          var geojsonFeature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
              "Name": element.Name,
              "Details": element["Treatment"],
              "Street View": getStreetView(mapping)
            },
            "geometry": mapping
          };
          geojsonFeature.properties["Treatment"] = element["Treatment"];
          features.push(geojsonFeature);
        }
      }
      return features;
    }
  });

  sectionLayer.on('data:loaded', function () {
    map.addLayer(markers);
  });
}
```

Here is working JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/3oLsx2t9/

Comment: This does not seem to be fixing the issue. Clicking a spiderfied element is still triggering unspiderfy.

Comment: See edited answer. I added JSFiddle example.

Comment: Just an update: somehow, my 'pointToLayer' visual customization is causing the issue... sort of. In my code, if I comment out the 'pointToLayer' section, your suggestion works perfectly. But with the 'pointToLayer' content - even if I replace the function calls with hardcoded colours - I still have the issue of spiderfied elements disappearing when clicked. And yet, if I add the same 'pointToLayer' code to your JSFiddle, there is no issue.

Comment: I modified my JSFiddle to also use `pointToLayer` option, but it still works OK. But I noticed you use some extended marker cluster `L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport`. What is this `.layerSupport`?

Comment: It's another plugin. I didn't write that part of the code, so I'm not sure why it's there, but I don't think it's causing the issue. When I remove it (so I just make a normal markerClusterGroup), the issue remains the same.

Comment: So there must be some difference in your implementation from my JSFiddle example.

Comment: Only now I noticed you're using `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` for GeoJSON layer. I'll test also with this plugin.

Comment: Tested with `L.GeoJSON.AJAX` and it still works.

Comment: Unfortunately, it must be code elsewhere on my page that is having the unintended, unexpected consequence of preventing default behaviour of spiderfied items. There is a lot of code involved and it would be very difficult to guess what is causing this, so I have shelved the issue and taken an alternate approach to displaying the data: when the items are spiderfied, a custom popup with all their data appears at the central (cluster) point. You can close this question for now if you want, but if I ever find the answer, I will post an update.

Comment: Answer is correct answer to solve the problem as described in the question, as it is obvious from JSFiddle. As such it deserves acceptance or it least upvote.